# accessing items in an json.net jarray in c#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

My API returns

```
{
  "result": [
    {
      "id": "51473",
      "name": "serv-vc",
      "modifydate": "2014-10-09 18:29:48.033",
      "expirationoff": "false",
      "createdate": "",
      "scheduleoff": "false",
    }
  ],
  "status": 0
}
```

which I've stored as a JObject reponseobj

I'm having trouble figuring out how to access `responseobj["result"][0]["id"]`.

Every time I try that, it gives an array about being out of bounds.

What am I missing?

I also tried

```
JArray resultarr = (JArray)responseobj.SelectToken("result");
resultarr[0]["id"]
```

but have the same results.

Comment: Are you sure your result array always has data?  You'll get an array out of bounds exception if it is empty and you try to access element 0 (or any other element).

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the response is in a string variable called `response`, this would do it:

```
JObject responseobj = JObject.Parse(response);
JObject result = (JObject)(responseobj.SelectToken("result") as JArray).First();
int id = result.Value<int>("id");
```

Comment: Best answer. Nice and clean.

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
JObject jObject = JObject.Parse( "{\"result\": [{\"id\": \"51473\", \"name\": \"serv-vc\", \"modifydate\": \"2014-10-09 18:29:48.033\", \"expirationoff\": \"false\", \"createdate\": \"\", \"scheduleoff\": \"false\", } ], \"status\": 0 }" );
```

And to access to the different nodes, you can use:

```
string name = jObject["result"]["name"].ToString();
string expirationoff = jObject["result"]["expirationoff"].ToString();
```

Or you can convert `result` in a new json a work on it

And to access to `result` you can do:

`var result = jObject["result"][0];`

Remember that you can have 0, 1, 2... x numbers of results in your json, then you need do reference to the first position.

Comment: You're missing the array index.  `result` is an array, and `name` and `expirationoff` are properties of an object inside the array.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what's your issue, but this seems to work for me :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    JObject j = JObject.Parse(
        "{\"result\": [{\"id\": \"51473\", \"name\": \"serv-vc\", \"modifydate\": \"2014-10-09 18:29:48.033\", \"expirationoff\": \"false\", \"createdate\": \"\", \"scheduleoff\": \"false\", } ], \"status\": 0 }" );
    var res = j["result"];
    Console.Out.WriteLine(res); 
    // show an arrays

    var maybe = j["result"][0];
    Console.Out.WriteLine(maybe);
    // shows the first object in the array

    var fail = j["result"][0]["id"];
    Console.Out.WriteLine(fail);
    // shows 51473
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var Jobj = ((JObject)RequestObject)["data"];
foreach (JObject content in Jobj.Children<JObject>()) {
    foreach (JProperty prop in content.Properties()) {
        Console.WriteLine(prop.Name);//the column name
        Console.WriteLine(prop.Value.ToString());// column value
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.