# Delete a member of JArray

Tags: c#, json.net

I have the below JSON

```
[
    {
        "Code": "Global Payroll",
        "Month1": 1,
        "Month2": 0,
        "Month3": 0,
        "Month4": null,
        "Month5": null,
        "Month6": null,
        "Month7": null,
        "Month8": null,
        "Month9": null,
        "Month10": null,
        "Month11": null,
        "Month12": null,
        "YTD": 1,
        "PercentOfTotal": "16.67%"
    },
    {
        "Code": "GV Payroll",
        "Month1": 0,
        "Month2": 0,
        "Month3": 3,
        "Month4": null,
        "Month5": null,
        "Month6": null,
        "Month7": null,
        "Month8": null,
        "Month9": null,
        "Month10": null,
        "Month11": null,
        "Month12": null,
        "YTD": 3,
        "PercentOfTotal": "50.00%"
    }  
]
```

What I wanted to do was somehow remove Month4,Month5 etc from the JSON and then convert it back to string.

I tried looking into JArray.remove method but that removes the item itself from the array. Can some one please tell me how I can completely remove properties from JArray.

Comment: You wouldn't use `JArray`, but rather `JObject`, targeting an item in the `JArray`. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/32153010/215552. For targeting an item in the `JArray`, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/26372250/215552

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var array = JArray.Parse(json);

foreach (JObject elem in array)
{
   foreach (var elementToRemove in new List<string>() {"Month4", "Month5" })
   {
       elem.Property(elementToRemove).Remove();
    }              
}

var resultJson = array.ToString();
```

Comment: When i am using this,it is giving me {} for that index

Answer (score 1):

JArray is for `[]` (array)

JObject is for `{}`(object)

`Month1 .. Month12` they are all objects. In which case you need to use `JObject`

```
JArray ja = JArray.Parse(json);
JObject jo = (JObject)ja[0];
jo.Property("Month4").Remove();
json = jo.ToString();
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/EpdpD4)

Answer (score 1):

You can call `Remove()` from the `JProperty` to remove them. Also instead of removing specific properties by name, you might want to just remove properties that are named "MonthX" whose value is null.

```
var json = /* your json here */;
var payrolls = JArray.Parse(json);

foreach(var payroll in payrolls)
{
    foreach (var property in payroll.Children<JProperty>().ToArray())
    {
        if (property.Name.StartsWith("Month") && property.Value.Type == JTokenType.Null)
            property.Remove();
    }
}

json = payrolls.ToString();
```